# How to use f:setPropertyActionListener in h:commandButton in JSF without navigation to other pages?

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I use a calendar in h:commandButton. I need to update a PanelGroup based on the date selected from the commandButton (calendar). The corresponding code is as follows:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="ui-tabs calendar-icons" onclick="generateCalender()">

    <f:setPropertyActionListener  target="dateValue" value="true"></f:setPropertyActionListener>

</h:commandButton>

<c:set var="formattedDate" value="#{dateValue == 'true' ? formatDate : currentDate}"/>
```

Each time i select a date, the panelGroup must be updated. But the page gets refreshed each time I clicked the button because the **type = "submit"** is the default type for h:commandButton. If I use the **type = "button"**, *f:setPropertyActionListener* is not working.

Is there any way other than using f:setPropertyActionListener to set values when the command button is clicked and set the value for *formattedDate* based on the obtained value?

Comment: Which JSF version are you using? As you've tagged Primefaces, there's a calendar component ready to use.

Comment: I am using JSF2.0 version. For your kind information, I cannot use calendar component for this project.

Comment: I guess you want to perform an ajax request and show the calendar with javascript later on. Just use a `f:ajax` inside the command button and call the `generateCalender()` javascript function in the ajax `oncomplete`